# Android hide keyboard on btn click

Tags: android, android-keypad

I want to hide keyboard on click event of a button. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 11, accepted):

to hide the virtual keyboard:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editView.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)
                                  getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 

inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),
                                     InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
```

I put this right after the onClick(View v) event.
You need to `import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;`

The keyboard hides when you click the button.